# Why does this formula not evaluate to true?

Tags: formula, workflow, field-update

I have a time based workflow but the criteria I have set up is not being evaluated to true even though the results are the value that I believe them to be. Here is the debug log showing the workflow formula and results:

```
12:04:46:282 WF_FORMULA Formula:AND(ISPICKVAL(Management_Response__c,""), 
ISNULL(Management_Response_Detail__c))|Values:Management_Response_Detail__c=null, 
Management_Response__c=null
```

Management_Response__c is a picklist and I am checking to see that nothing has been selected and Management_Response_Detail__c is a textarea and I am also checking to make sure it has not been filled out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the ISBLANK function instead of ISNULL. You get the wrong results for text otherwise.

See this much better answer for more explanation [ISBLANK vs ISNULL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/isblank-vs-isnull)

Comment: If the next line in the debug log does not say it evaluated to false - is it assumed to have evaluated to true. Because now I get no indication of whether it passed or failed and no actual display of the values they equated to.