# On empty image display another image

Tags: visualforce, image-formula

I was wondering if it is possible to display another picture in case the picture is empty.

I tried this formula but is not working, any ideas?

```
IF(ProductImage3__c != null, 
  IMAGE("http://images.domain.com"+"/"+ProductImage3__c, Name,200,200), 
  IMAGE("http://images.domain.com"+"/"+ProductImage2__c, Name, 200,200)
)
```

Comment: Try adding those images as static resources, it will work.

Comment: If the issue is the boolean expression check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/isblank-vs-isnull.

Comment: Keith,Thank you for the info, is good to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You only have 1 underscore for ProdctImage3_c, so it won't compile, for one.
2. Use ISBLANK instead of != Null, it's a friendlier way of checking for nulls.
3. You don't need a separate + "/" +, just include that as part of your URL string.
4. You may want to add some default image in case ProductImage2__c is null.

I've tested the following formula out on my dev org, which works:

```
IMAGE(
    "http://images.domain.com/" +     
    IF(
        ISBLANK(ProductImage3__c),
        ProductImage2__c,
        ProductImage3__c
    )
    ,Name
    ,200
    ,200
)
```

Comment: James, thank you! it works just fine. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing no image? What is the error you see?

Your formula seems to be right, one suggestion I can point you towards is make sure you

> treat blank fields as blanks than zeros

since you are using image on a text formula.

Comment: Good to see you back buddy :)

Comment: Thank you man ! I will try your solution and  let you know