# Formula field not calculating properly with null

Tags: custom-object, formula, custom-field, formula-field

We have a formula field in a custom object that does not calculate properly. Although the value of the field in the if condition is not null, the result is always zero. The formula is:

```
if(field1__c!=null,field2__c - field3__c,0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing it to

```
IF(ISBLANK(field1__c), 0 , field2__c - field3__c)
```

its always better to use the inbuilt formula functions..

you can refer [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/isblank-vs-isnull) to understand the difference between ISNULL and ISBLANK functions

Comment: Thanks Vamsi That helped. Any idea why that wouldn't work without giving any errors?

Comment: I think != null doesn't cover empty strings ( != '' ) ISBLANK covers both the checks.

Comment: More to the point, *text* fields are not NULL in formula terminology. Only other non-text types, like numbers and dates, can be null. ISBLANK, however, covers both the null case (like dates and numbers) as well as empty text strings.