# ISBLANK vs ISNULL how does it evalaute

Tags: validation-rule

I am writing a validation rule as follows : `AND(NOT(ISBLANK(LookupField__c)), checkField__c )`

The above works fine and have no issues, but when I change it to as follows :
`AND(NOT(ISNULL(LookupField__c)), checkField__c )` the validation fails.

I observed that when I having ISNULL, even if the lookup field has no value its evaluated to false, does in turn evaluating to TRUE due to NOT check. Not sure why this is happening and what is the difference in evaluation of same criteria with ISBLANK since that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The use of ISNULL and ISBLANK depends on the type of field. ISNULL always return FALSE for a textfield. Please refer to thiS Link :
[ISNULL VS ISBLANK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/isblank-vs-isnull)

[ISNULL VS ISBLANK](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008w4UIAQ)

Regards,

Ajay