# Null values isn't seen as null

Tags: formula, null

I have a text field that has nothing in it. I created a formula to check if it is null, but it keeps coming up that it exists.

```
IF(ISNULL({!textfield}),"Null","Exists")
```

There isn't a hidden space or anything like that in the field. It doesn't matter what field type I am referencing, everything comes back as "exists".

Comment: Even when I make the formula simply ISNULL({!TextField}) with a type boolean, it still comes up false. And if I do LEN() to get the number of characters is comes up 0. I can use that as a workaround, but I don't know why this would happen or if this is an error.

Comment: Your question has an [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8828/20830)

Comment: Weird that that question didn't show up in the related questions bit when i was tying in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [ISBLANK](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISBLANK) instead. ISNULL is used for types of values like numbers and dates, but formulas evaluate text fields to an empty string (a "blank") if they contain no data.

> Use ISBLANK instead of ISNULL in new formulas. ISBLANK has the same functionality as ISNULL, but also supports text fields. Salesforce will continue to support ISNULL, so you do not need to change any existing formulas.