# How to handle optionally null related objects in process builder?

Tags: custom-object, process-builder, null, owner

We have a custom object that can be associated with an account. Since this object type is usually created by an automated process, we'd like to trigger emails to account owners when these objects are created and associated with one of their accounts. Seems like an ideal use case for process builder, right?

Unfortunately I'm coming up against a problem because not all the instances of this object are actually linked to an account. I figure I need to check whether an account is linked before trying to access the account owner's name.

Based on this answer, I've tried the following:

```
NOT(ISNULL([My_Custom_Object__c].Account__c)) &&
[My_Custom_Object__c].Account__c.Owner.LastName = "SurnameOfAnAccountOwner"
```

But I'm still having issues. Is there anything glaringly wrong with this?

*Unfortunately, I don't receive emails with detailed errors - I only know this isn't working because of generic errors in the automated process that's trying to create the custom object instances.*

Comment: Second validation is unnecessary since an Account will always have an owner.

Comment: Good call @AlexanderAeonsTorn. Is it possible that this is tripping me up?

Comment: I don't think so. But its redundant. I also don't understand at all the last validation you're doing there. Could you explain me please?  Could it be that this last validation is messing things up avoiding the rule to validate correctly and send the email?

Try to just do the first check. and send the email to the account Owner.

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn The last check is to ensure that the account owner is one that we want to send emails to. Since only a subset of account owners want these notifications, the idea is to have one line in process builder for each of them.

Comment: Oh, okey, then makes sense to leave it there. Try with just those 2 checks and tell me. Put you lastname user on the second check and create a records to test if you receive the email properly.

Comment: @AlexanderAeonsTorn Alas, that is still erroring. Will update question to at least remove the superfluous line.

Comment: this is covered here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8827/2602 try: `NOT(ISBLANK(...))`

Comment: @cropredy Changing this seems to have fixed it. If you wanted to make this into an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some time now, [SFDC has recommended](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#ISBLANK) that one use `ISBLANK(..)` in lieu of `ISNULL(..)`. As [Matt Lacey describes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8827/2602), ISNULL behaves differently for text and lookup fields than ISBLANK.

So, rewrite your expression to:

```
NOT(ISBLANK([My_Custom_Object__c].Account__c)) &&
[My_Custom_Object__c].Account__c.Owner.LastName = "SurnameOfAnAccountOwner"
```

Things are a bit different in APEX:

- If field `Foo__c.Account__c` is a lookup field, then `if (foo.Account__c == null)` works as expected.
- If field `Foo__c.SomeTextField__c` is a field of type Text, then one uses

  ```
  if (String.isBlank(f.SomeTextField__c))
  ```

  to handle both null and empty string situations.