# Problem on Formula field

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a formula (return type=date) field , it populates based on two custom date fields whichever is populated first in those two custom fields.

`Original_Issue_date__c` is the formula field, formula code is as follows:

```
TODAY() - max(
    if(
        isnull(TODAY()- SOM_Conditional_License_Issue_Date__c ),
        0,
        TODAY()-SOM_Conditional_License_Issue_Date__c
    ),
    if(
        isnull(TODAY()- MUSW__Issue_Date__c ),
        0,
        TODAY()-MUSW__Issue_Date__c
    )
)
```

The problem is this formula works good if either or both fields have values, but if both fields are blank it is populating with today's date.

In this case, I don't want that to be populated with today's date, just need that to be blank in this case.

Comment: You've provided us with a statement, but have not told us what your problem is. Please [edit] your question to include more details such as - The problem you're having, - Details about the api names of the fields involved in your formula, - The formula that you currently have, - Any error messages that you're seeing, copied **verbatim**

Comment: @user If a below answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you see today's date is that your formula evaluates to TODAY() - 0. You can fix that pretty simply with the following.

```
if(
    AND(
        ISBLANK(SOM_Conditional_License_Issue_Date__c),
        ISBLANK(MUSW__Issue_Date__c)
    ),
    null,
    TODAY() - max(
        if(
            ISBLANK(TODAY()- SOM_Conditional_License_Issue_Date__c ),
            0,
            TODAY()-SOM_Conditional_License_Issue_Date__c
        ),
        if(
            ISBLANK(TODAY()- MUSW__Issue_Date__c ),
            0,
            TODAY()-MUSW__Issue_Date__c
        )
    )
)
```

You could also do some logic to determine if the formula evaluates to 0 as opposed to checking the dates to see if they're blank but that would significantly increase the compile size of the formula. This fix is much simpler.

Also, you should use [ISBLANK instead of ISNULL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/isblank-vs-isnull)

**Original Answer (before question provided more detail):**

Use a Process Builder to populate your new field instead of a formula. Your logic should be something like "If Original_Issue_date__c is empty, and SOM_Conditional_License_Issue_Date__c or MUSW__Issue_Date__c is changed, set Original_Issue_date__c to the changed value". This will make it so the date is populated the first time a date is entered, but when the second date is entered, the field wont be empty and your PB wont update it ensuring you have the first date entered.

Comment: Thanks, actually i got confused by populating one of the field with future date. Anyways i got it worked now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be blank when both fields are blank, you need to add that as an `IF` condition:

```
IF(
    AND(ISNULL(Date1__c), ISNULL(Date2__c)),
    null,
    /*current formula as else condition here*/
)
```