# Help: validation rule (Product/Product Family)

Tags: validation-rule, sales-cloud

I need to build a validation rule with the following requirements in **'Product'** object:

1. Family Product = 'PestControl' (picklist/native)
2. TypeProduct__c = 'Contract' **OR** 'Active' (picklist/custom)
3. IF TypeProduct__c = 'Contract' THEN **Frequency__c is required** (Number/custom)
   **OR**
4. IF TypeProduct__c = 'Active' THEN **Validity__c is required** (Number/custom)

My challenge is: generate an error message for each of these scenarios, independently.

I was able to validate for one scenario, but I was unable to reconcile the two scenarios. My unsuccessfully attempt:

```
OR (
    AND(
     ISPICKVAL(Family, 'PestControl'),
     ISPICKVAL(TypeProduct__c, 'Contract'),
     ISBLANK(Frequency__c)
    ),
    AND(
     ISPICKVAL(Family, 'PestControl'),
     ISPICKVAL(TypeProduct__c, 'Active'),
     ISBLANK(Validity__c) 
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried `ISNULL` instead of `ISBLANK`?

Comment: Also, what option do you have selected for treatment of blank values (directly under the box where you enter your formula)? Treat blanks as blanks, or treat blanks as zeros?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, I tried using ISNULL but it didn't work. ISBLANK works. Derek F, I'm treating blanks as blanks.

Comment: I tried creating two validation rules for each scenario and it worked!

AND(
 ISPICKVAL(Family, 'PestControl'),
 ISPICKVAL(TypeProduct__c, 'Contract'),
 ISBLANK(Frequency__c)
)

--------------------------------------------

AND(
 ISPICKVAL(Family, 'PestControl'),
 ISPICKVAL(TypeProduct__c, 'Active'),
 ISBLANK(Validity__c)
)

Comment: @AdrianLarson bro ISNULL is a legacy, we should be using ISBLANK. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/isblank-vs-isnull

Comment: I tested your combined validation rule, and it is working. Not sure why it isn't working for you. But yes, you can also separate it to have different Validation rules if you want more specific error messages

Comment: Thanks @compski !